# Phonegap HTML5 / Android App - Iframe height issue

Tags: android, html, iframe, jquery-mobile, cordova

We have built a HTML5 app which dynamically loads an iFrame to display external content.  This solution worked fine until the release of android 4.0 - which seems to have changed the way that iframe rendering works?

It appears it can no longer detect the height, it shows a small scrollable box containing roughly 50px height of a 900px tall page. I have tried setting height to 100% - which works visually - but the app gets strange click results on anything beneath the page fold!

It works fine if I manually set heights for each frame - but due to the dynamic content this is very impractical..  Also as the app has a certain level of internal nav within the iframe - the sub pages can be a separate height to the original iframe height - again this did work fine in previous versions of Android.

Does anybody have any advice/explanations?

Comment: I have also recently built an app using phonegap and realised that 4.0 + particularly 4.0.3 have a lot of web view bugs and therefore a lot of things that work in the previous version will no longer work properly in 4.0 upwards. Unfortunetly Google are not too bothered about this as they are trying to push for more native apps. Sorry that I cannot help with your issue, just something to consider for the future.

Comment: You could try using something other than pixels such as em

Comment: cheers for the advice, unfortunately we are stuck with iframes for now due a complex backend system.  Annoying issue though heh!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you're still stuck,  I've just found this workaround...

```
<iframe src='externalcontent.htm' width='100%' scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' id='theiFrame' onLoad='fixiFrame();'></iframe>

function fixiFrame () {
   if ((android) && (androidVersion > 3)) {
      iFrameContentHeight = document.getElementById('theiFrame').contentDocument.body.offsetHeight;
      document.getElementById('theiFrame').style.height = iFrameContentHeight + 'px';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Android 4 and 5:

```
document.getElementById('theIframe').style.height = document.getElementById('theParent').offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Don't forget the '+px'