# Changing iframe src breaks scrolling in Android Phonegap application

Tags: android, iframe, cordova

I've an interesting bug here for a Phonegap application in android. I first noticed that the scrolling wasn't working in the emulator, or on some specific devices (It does work on my phone, wich is platform 2.3) and tried every recommendation to fix that including multiple here in SO suggesting; 1, native side fixes and 2, adding the iScroll library. However, none of the solutions worked. Also the unavailable scrolling only affected specific pages, and not the entire app.

I've narrowed the problem down to this line of code, which replaces the src attribute of an iframe. It is intended to show the thumbnail of a youtube video where the url is being obtained via an external content api.

```
$('#video').attr('src', newUrl);
```

and the iFrame markup

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" id="video" type="text/html" src="js/views/loading.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I've tried hard coding the url in the markup, and it works fine, It's something about the act of replacing the iframe's source that breaks page scrolling.

I'm sing Phonegap/Cordova 1.8.1 and the minimum target android platform is 2.2

Thank you in advance for any help.

*Edit: Seems to be something involved with the viewport as removing the tag stops whatever is breaking the scrolling.

Comment: Removing what tag fixes it? I seem to be having some iframe related issues myself. I'm on the iPad, and it is weird. Two finger scroll sort of works, but not well. I'm trying to show a file in the iframe, like a PDF. Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an Android application I was creating using PhoneGap. The issue I had was that as the data in the iframe changed, the amount of scroll-able space changed as well so some pages would scroll too far and some not enough.

In order to fix this, you have to use some JavaScript to adjust the height of the iframe based on it's content when the content is loaded.

I found my answer from this question: [Phonegap HTML5 / Android App - Iframe height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258951/phonegap-html5-android-app-iframe-height-issue)

The answer from that question suggests using the onload attribute on the iframe to call a javascript function that adjusts the height of the iframe to match the content.

The javascript itself looks like this: where obj is the iframe element that gets passed into the function.

```
function resizeIFrame(obj){
     obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

Now, anytime the source of the iframe changes, it will adjust the height based on that content and should fix your scrolling issue.