# Avoid fullscreen iframe with Phonegap on Android

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, fullscreen

Sorry to post this question again, I saw some Issues about that on Stackoverflow but I can't find any solution...

When I try to display an iframe with Phonegap on Android, the iframe goes fullscreen and don't let any place for the rest of the page.

Here is the code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    index
    <iframe src="iframe.html" width="10px" height="10px"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    iframe!
  </body>
</html>
```

here are some related topics:
[Phonegap HTML5 / Android App - Iframe height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258951/phonegap-html5-android-app-iframe-height-issue)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/BA35Yna2-dI

Is there any solution?

I also search on the [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?) of Cordova without success...